# Flutter: CachedNetworkImage not caching image

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I have a widget that retrieves images from Firebase Storage. But now I want to cache these images, to make the user experience more neat (and also avoid unneccessary calls to Firebase).

So I found CachedNetworkImageProvider which sounded like everything I wanted. I tried implementing it as stated in the docs, but it doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

Here's my code:

```
class FirebaseStorageImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String fileName;
  final StorageReference storageLocation;

  FirebaseStorageImage(
      {@required this.fileName, @required this.storageLocation});

  Future<String> _getImageURL() async {
    final StorageReference ref = storageLocation.child(fileName + ".jpg");

    try {
      var url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      return url;
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _getImageURL(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
            snapshot.hasData) {
          return Image(
            //image: NetworkImage(snapshot.data),
            image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(snapshot.data),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          );
        } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          //RETURN THIS WHILE WAITING FOR IMAGE
          return Text("Waiting....");
        } else {
          //RETURN THIS IF NO IMAGE WAS FOUND AT THAT LOCATION
          return Image(
            image: AssetImage("assets/images/placeholder.png"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work ? Do you have an error to share or a screenshot of what you have ?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but to answer your question: After further research I realized that probably it's not the `CachedNetworkImage` that doesn't work, but the way I'm implementing it in this Widget is bad, because it still goes to the `_getImageUrl()` future and gets the downloadURL which then takes some time. The result is that it takes some time for the images to load in, but the intended behaviour should be to just retrieve the images from cached memory if the are previously cached. Any idea on how I can do this in this widget? Maybe a check to see if the image is already cached?

Comment: @TesteurManiak Any idea on a nice implementation of this?

Comment: The thing is that the CachedNetworkImage's widget doesn't tell you beforehand if the image is cached or not. you have no choice but asynchronously get the download url a way or another. You can try to make a fork of the package to check how it loads a cached image so you can check it too.

Comment: @TesteurManiak Yeah, I kind of understand now how it works. Probably it retrieves the cached image, but the widget takes some time to load the image not because it downloads from Firebase, but because it need to await the `Future _getImageURL()`. There isn't a way around this? Or can I somehow first check if the downloadURL is cached? If yes, then don't await the future and go directly to `CachedNetworkImage`? If no, await the future.

Comment: A way around might be to cache the image's url with a database or a shared preferences, might be faster than waiting for your firebase.

Answer (score 0):

The way [CachedNetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) works is it still needs to have the url of the image to be loaded. Once the url is provided to the Widget, it can display the cached image if it was stored previously. You may want to consider storing the image urls locally if they're being fetched before being displayed. A workaround for this is storing the url with [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences).