# Using CachedNetworkImage inside of Futurebuilder Still shows progress indicator after image is cached

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, flutter-image

I would like to retrieve the image from the cache after looking it up the first time but since my URL is getting stored in a future it seems that I'm awaiting the future every time which in turn is causing the ProgressIndecator to show even when the image is cached. Which kinda defeats the purpose of caching.

[Flutter: CachedNetworkImage not caching image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59956627/flutter-cachednetworkimage-not-caching-image) -
What TesteurManiak stated in this post seems to make sense to whats happening in my situation

Here is my code

```
class ImageLayerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  ImageLayerWidget({Key key, this.layer}) : super(key: key);

  final AsyncMemoizer<models.Image> _memorizer = AsyncMemoizer();
  final models.ImageLayer layer;

  Future<models.Image> _fetchData() async {
    return this._memorizer.runOnce(() async {
      return await StorageFile<models.Image>(path: layer.path).getDatatoRam();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _fetchData(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snap) {
            if (snap.hasData) {
              return Image(
                image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(snap.data.path),
              );
            }
            return LinearProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am using an AsyncMemoizer to cache my image model class which holds the URL retrieved from ref.getDownloadURL();.  This didn't really seem to help. I want it to only show the progress indicator on the first fetch then cache the image so the user doesn't see the indicator again.

I've tried so many things.  Can anyone help?

Update:

As GrahamD suggested I also tried this

```
class ImageLayerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  ImageLayerWidget({Key key, this.layer}) : super(key: key);

  final models.ImageLayer layer;

  @override
  _ImageLayerWidget createState() => _ImageLayerWidget();
}

class _ImageLayerWidget extends State<ImageLayerWidget> {
  Future<models.Image> _future;

  Future<models.Image> _fetchData() async {
    return await StorageFile<models.Image>(path: widget.layer.path)
        .getDatatoRam();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = _fetchData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _future,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snap) {
            if (snap.hasData) {
              return Image(
                image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(snap.data.path),
              );
            }
            return LinearProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not solve the problem.  The LinearProgressIndicator always shows when returning to the same image.  I also tried putting _future inside the stateful part of the widget but also didn't help. It's as if the snapshot is resolving the future every time. I even propagated this style of state up the widget tree.  Still no fix. I'll keep trying things but I think it's the way I'm using ChachedNetworkImage with futures.

Comment: You need to assign _fetchData() to a variable in initState and then reference that variable  in future:   you are rerunning _fetchData() every time the build method runs.

Comment: tried it.  still get the same result.   the indicator always shows.  also using AsyncMemoizer so any subsequent calls to _fetchdata will return the same future that it got the first time.