# CachedNetworkImage Widget not caching firebase images, works on other links such as unsplash

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using a stream builder to retrieve data from firestore and using flutter_carousel_widget to show the a slidable card but each time the card moves out of viewport the images are gone and when comes into viewport it is retrieved from firebase again.

**HomeScreen.dart:**

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("special_offers")
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
                    specialOffers = snapshot.data!.docs;
                final offers = specialOffers.map((e) {
                  return SpecialOffer.fromMap(e.id, e.data());
                }).toList();
                return FlutterCarousel(
                  items: offers
                      .map(
                        (e) => Card(
                          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                          child: Stack(
                            children: [
                              //image
                              CachedNetworkImage(
                                imageUrl: e.image,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                width: double.infinity,
                                placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                    const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                    const Icon(Icons.error),
                              ),
                              //text
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 70, left: 20, right: 20),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Chip(
                                      label: Text(
                                        "${e.discount}% OFF",
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                      ),
                                      side: BorderSide.none,
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(
                                      height: 5,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      e.title,
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 22,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(
                                      height: 8,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      e.subtitle,
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 15,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                  options: CarouselOptions(
                    autoPlay: true,
                    enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                    showIndicator: true,
                    height: 250,
                    slideIndicator: CircularWaveSlideIndicator(),
                    viewportFraction: 1,
                  ),
                );
              }
              return Container();
            },
          ),
```

**Firebase Firestore Collection:**
[image]

**The problem:**
[video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A3uNoZERr6iEiCjYBP6qjl1KKo47XFn9/view?usp=sharing)

There is similar question asked here: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59956627/flutter-cachednetworkimage-not-caching-image)

The answer says that the url should be stored,but I am mapping the url to the object or may be I am wrong.
If the answer is correct then how I can make stream builder to listen to data only once ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the url is loaded again from Firebase, it is probably loaded from the cache but it still takes some times to render in the widget.
For some reason the carousel items are rebuilt each time you swipe.

I do not know if flutter_carousel_widget to know if it should preload the widget... can you try to add a `Key(e.image)` to each card of the carousel or to each `cachedNetworkImage` to tell Flutter that that widget does not need to be rebuilt if it contains the same imageUrl ?

Comment: I tried this but it didn't worked.For better understantding I added print in the carousel widget and cachedImage widget the result in the console was : 3
I/flutter (11016): carousel rebuild
48
I/flutter (11016): image rebuild
The cachedImage widget is fetching the image every time it is on the viewport.
Also I tried this with unsplash images it only fetches image once,only with firebase the images are not cached.

Comment: can you try to manually add a cacheKey in the cachedNetworkImage widget. You can use maybe e.id instead of the url so that you associate the cache with the firebase object instead of the image url

Comment: I added the cacheKey: e.id but it didn't worked. Like I said if I used unsplash image url or any other web image url the image gets cached but if I use firebase storage image the image isn't cached

Comment: I tried this still not caching.I asked chatgpt about this and it told me to use custom cache manager I also tried it and it's still not caching.Problem is there are many images in my homescreen which are fetched from firebase and my app crashes if I used another widgets with images in my homescreen

Comment: For the crash, just swap the list of item in the carousel with a carousel builder: https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_carousel_widget/latest/#build-item-widgets-on-demand, try combining the builder with assigned a key to each element as said in my first answer